# Showing linearity of functionals on $c[a,b]$ and $l^2$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Erwin Kreyszig Section 2.8, Problem 1:

---

Define a functional on $C[a,b]$ by fixing $t_0\in[a,b]$ and setting:

$$f_1(x)=x(t_0)$$

---

Define a second functional on $l^2$ by choosing a fixed $a=(\alpha_j)\in l^2$ and setting $$f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \xi_j\alpha_j$$ where $x=(\xi_j)\in l^2$

Show these two functionals are linear

---

This question has been self-answered by the OP(me).

Comment: If you have found this at some point. It may be of interest that  [Q2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083268/erwin-kreyszig-section-2-8-problem-2-what-is-the-norm-of-these-two-functionals), [Q3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083286/erwin-kreyszigs-introductory-functional-analysis-with-applications-section-2-8), [Q4](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083346/erwin-kreyszigs-introductory-functional-analysis-with-applications-section-2-8) from this section of the textbook have answers on this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $1)$
We want to show this functional is linear.

I.e. $f(ax_1+bx_2)=af(x_1)+bf(x_2)$

---

$f(ax_1+bx_2) = (ax_1+bx_2)(t_0)=(ax_1)(t_0) + (bx_2)(t_0)=ax_1(t_0)+bx_2(t_0)=af(x_1)+bf(x_2)$$\square$

---

For $2)$ We want to show this functional is linear:

I.e. $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(m\xi_j\alpha_j + n\zeta_j\alpha_j \right)=f(mx_1+nx_2)=mf(a)+nf(b) = m\sum_{j=1}^\infty \xi_j\alpha_j+n\sum_{j=1}^\infty \zeta_j\alpha_j$

We have: $$\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(m\xi_j\alpha_j + n\zeta_j\alpha_j \right)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(m\xi_j\alpha_j\right) + \sum_{j=1}^\infty\left(n\zeta_j\alpha_j \right)=m\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\xi_j\alpha_j\right) + n\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left(\zeta_j\alpha_j \right)$$

As required